# Should failed login pages really be returning an HTTP 200 status?

Tags: http, semantics, http-status-codes

I noticed today that when you try to log in to Amazon and get your password wrong it returns a `200 OK` response. I'm sure most websites also operate in this fashion. Semantically speaking, is this really the appropriate code to return? Wouldn't a code of `401 Unauthorized` make more sense or am I thinking of that status code in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am sending the data via ajax I will use jQuery's `.done()` and `.fail()` functions. If the login failed for any reason I want to invoke the methods in `.fail()` So I will send back a `400 (bad request)` header, otherwise the methods in `.done()` would be fired.

But if you were redirecting to a login page with the failed details then yes, a 200 would be appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Think of it this way: You're authorized to see the failed log-in page, therefore a 200 HTTP status code is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are talking about web sites which are displayed in the web browser HTTP code `200 OK` is right. Since the user is allowed to see the page which displays "Authentication failed".

When the user (or web service client) tries to access a resource which he shouldn't belong to `401 Unauthorized` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

[401](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) is reserved for authentication in the HTTP layer:

> The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field

You are talking about applications which were designed to implement authentication without http's authentication. Therefore it's consistent not to reflect failures by HTTP status code.